# Hibernate Criteria Query like operator on CLOB (Postgres 8.4)

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a criteria query not really working. Here the model:

```
@Entity
public class Flaw extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private String text;
    ...
```

This query is going to be executed by hibernate (from Logs):

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        ...
        flaw0_.text as col_7_0_,
        ...
    from
        Flaw flaw0_,
    where
        ...
        and (
            flaw0_.text like ?
        ) 
    order by
        flaw0_.text desc
```

But then I get the following StackTrace:

```
3171 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
3171 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: operator does not exist: text ~~ bigint
3198 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing
```

With oder properties it works fine, just with the like operator on the CLOB it is not working. Is this a Hibernate or Postgres problem? Or is this type of query not possible on CLOBs?

I am using:

- Hibernate 3.6.3
- PostgreSQL 8.4.8
- PostgreSQL 8.3 JDBC3 with SSL (build 603)

Any Ideas?

**Update:**
I did some further investigation:

- The above annotation creates correctly a `text` postgres type
- If I run the sql query , that hibernate prints out, it works.

BR

Rene-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying around I found the following solution which worked for me. I had to add the following annotation, and now it works:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear possible, as CLOBs are fully supported in your version of Postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html

Comment: Here's an interesting thread on this same topic: http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database/browse_thread/thread/d72435d1382c39c4.  The user there needed to modify the Hibernate code to get it to work; not sure if the update made its way into the main Hibernate trunk.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally found a solution without code modification. See my answer.